# Parse function, python (binary search tree)

Tags: python, parsing, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a parse function.  "From an infix stream of tokens, and the current index into the token stream, construct and return the tree, as a collection of Nodes, that represents the expression" This is what i have came up with so far:

```
def parse(tokens, i = 0):
   lst = []
   token = lst[i]
   left, i = parse(lst, i+1)
   right, i = parse(lst, i+1)

   if token.isdigit():
       return mkLiteralNode(token)
   elif token.isidentifier():
       return mkVariableNode(token)
   else:
       left, i = parse(lst, i+1)
       right, i = parse(lst, i+1)

   return True
```

So in general, `token.isdigit` means that this command has to return an integer, which is `mkLiteralNode`, and `token.isidentifier` should return variable, or `mkVariableNode`.  I am getting an error when testing this function and the error is:

```
    token = lst[i]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorry for inconvenience, but i researched and found another approach to this problem:

```
def parse(tokens):

   tok = next(tokens)

   if tok.isdigit():
       return ('literal', tok)
   elif tok == "+":
       return ('add', parse(tokens), parse(tokens))
   elif tok == '-':
       return ('subtract', parse(tokens), parse(tokens))
   elif tok == "*":
       return ('multiply', parse(tokens), parse(tokens))
   elif tok == "//":
       return ('divide', parse(tokens), parse(tokens))
   else:
       return ('variable', tok)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is right in the previous line:

```
lst = 0
```

You are making `lst` an `int` and then trying to access it as a list which throws the error you are seeing. `token = lst[i]` probably should be:

```
token = tokens[i]
```

Comment: oh, i see now, but i changed it to 'lst = []' to tuple, it is now showing an error : list index out of range, same problem with 'token = lst[i]'

Comment: `lst = []` means `lst` is an empty list. `lst[i]` for any value of i means you are trying to access ith element. When `lst` has no elements.